In Swin-Transformer, Is each token (to-embedding) value an integer?
Swin-Transformer transform the image to tokens to input to transformer.
Is each token (before-embedding) value an integer?
In practice, where is this done? https://github.com/microsoft/Swin-Transformer
The code (
self.head = nn.Linear(self.num_features, num_classes))
seems not output integers?

Input embeddings are image patches, not integers. The code you linked is for the output layer of a classification model, so of course the shape of the output matches the number of classes.
